# Exporting SMS messages from iPhone into plain text files

Tags: iphone, unix

Can I get my SMS messages off my iPhone and into a plain text format?  I tried
idevicebackup2 for libimodibledevice, but it doesn't work (error messages
below).  Besides it seems to operate with an encryption password I don't know.
Using Linux.

```
Moving 128 files
[==================================================]  99% Finished
Moving 128 files
[==================================================]  99% Finished
Moving 128 files
[==================================================]  99% Finished
Moving 128 files
[==================================================]  99% Finished
Moving 128 files
[==================================================] 100% Finished
Moving 128 files
[==================================================] 100% Finished
Moving 128 files
[==================================================] 100% Finished
Moving 128 files
[==================================================] 100% Finished
Moving 128 files
[==================================================] 100% Finished
Moving 55 files
[==================================================] 100% Finished
Moving 1 file
[==================================================] 100% Finished
Moving 1 file
[==================================================] 100% Finished
[==================================================] 100% Finished
Removing 1 file
Could not remove 'iph/d342710805963ec35279371e6af9093234781262/Snapshot': Directory not empty (39)
[==================================================] 100% Finished
ErrorCode 104: Error removing snapshot directory (MBErrorDomain/104). Underlying error: Directory not empty (MBErrorDomain/100).
Received 2632 files from device.
Backup Failed (Error Code 104).
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked well for me on Windows: https://www.copytrans.net/support/how-to-convert-iphone-sms-to-plain-text/

But because I use a Mac from day to day I use this, however it does require you to backup the device before you can extract the texts: https://www.imactools.com/tutorial/extract-sms-messages-from-iphone-backup

Comment: There's also https://www.jwz.org/hacks/sms-backup-iphone.pl , which worked back when I used it but don't know if it works today.  Ask jwz if it still works, he will know.